# Postfix smtp user

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I have recently managed to get Postfix smtp working on my Ubuntu server.

The problem is that in order to get the mail client on my local system to send emails from the server, I am having to use the login details of one of my server's user accounts. I can't give these details to anyone else, as they would be able to log into my server!

How can I set up a user which can't log into the server, but which can use the smtp facilities of Postfix?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back when dinosaurs roamed the earth, we'd set their shell '/sbin/nologin' so they couldn't get shell/ftp/etc access to the machine.

Comment: Thanks synthesizerpatel, that worked great. Very much appreciated : )